# How to withdraw from an offline / paper wallet into Bitcoin-Qt on Mac?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, offline, paper-wallet

I understand how to create and deposit into an offline wallet, but how do I retrieve the BitCoins back onto a local Bitcoin-Qt wallet on a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto: **Help** > **Debug Window** > **Console**

In the input box, type:

```
importprivkey [YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE]
```

Example:

```
importprivkey 5J5njVrrim5SX9LF56GPx571iViS7LGqpH5TH49ncfaaWFtzMjY
```